# Differentiating between xpaths

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I was wondering how to differentiate between the paths between these two HTMLs.

//button[@class="search-results__pagination-next-button"] seems to get both of the items.

```html
<button class="search-results__pagination-next-button" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-5268="5268">
    <span class="v-align-middle">
      Next
    </span>
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon" class="v-align-middle" size="small"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M9,8L5,2.07,6.54,1l4.2,6.15a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0,1.69L6.54,15,5,13.93Z" class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path></svg></li-icon>
  </button>



<button disabled="" class="search-results__pagination-next-button" type="button" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-4958="4958">
    <span class="v-align-middle">
      Next
    </span>
    <li-icon aria-hidden="true" type="chevron-right-icon" class="v-align-middle" size="small"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="24px" height="24px" x="0" y="0" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" class="artdeco-icon" focusable="false"><path d="M9,8L5,2.07,6.54,1l4.2,6.15a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,0,1.69L6.54,15,5,13.93Z" class="small-icon" style="fill-opacity: 1"></path></svg></li-icon>
  </button>
```

Comment: That xpath says "find all `button` elements with `class=search-results__pagination-next-button`, so yes, it finds both of those buttons.  I see that the top button has an attribute named `data-ember-action-5268` and the other has an attribute named `data-ember-action-4958`.  Are these attributes constant? 
 If so, you could use those to search.  If not, you could look for the buttons based on their specific location within the document tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first button is enabled, the second is disabled.

To match the first one, you can use the xpath: `//button[@class="search-results__pagination-next-button" and count(@disabled) = 0]`

To match the second one, you can try: `//button[@class="search-results__pagination-next-button" and count(@disabled) != 0]`.

The `count` function counts the number of nodes. Here, we count the attribute `@disabled` even if its value is the empty string.

Comment: Is the second button really disabled?  It has `disabled=""`.  I'm used to disabled elements having `disabled="disabled"` or `disabled="true"`.

Comment: You right John. But I can’t see the HTML on my smartphone. Only an assumption. But in term of xpath, it will make the diff.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the solution suggested, you can also use combination of absolute (Using location of element) and relative(Using attribute of element). As complete HTML code is not shared I would not be able to share exact answer.

Just for example let say two elements have same attribute

```
**element-1**
<div class="cls1">
 <Button id= btn-one> and <Button id= btn-one> 
</div>

**element-2**
<div class="cls2">
 <Button id= btn-one> and <Button id= btn-one> 
</div>
```

So below two xpaths can be used to identify elements uniquely

```
    //div[@class='cls1']/button[id ='btn-one']
    //div[@class='cls2']/button[id='btn-one']
```